# How to get not escaped value from json

Tags: json, sql-server

I have inserted some test data like below:

```
INSERT INTO tblDataInfo (lookupkey, lookupvalue, scope) 
VALUES ('diskname', '/dev/sdb', 'common')
```

yours sincerely

I wanted to query this data and like to obtain the query output in JSON format.

I have used the query

```
select lookupvalue as 'disk.name' 
from tblDataInfo 
where lookupkey = 'diskname' FOR JSON PATH;
```

This query returns

```
[{"disk":{"name":"\/dev\/sdb"}}]
```

which is escaping all my forward slashes (`/`) using the escape character (`\`). How can I have my output not to put escape-character (`\`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query returns result that you need:

```
select json_query ('{"name":"' + lookupvalue + '"}') as 'disk'
from tblDataInfo 
where lookupkey = 'diskname'
for json path;
```