# How to get unescaped value from JSON PATH

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Basing my question on the topic in the link:
[How to get not escaped value from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345532/how-to-get-not-escaped-value-from-json)

This is the query answer given from the link above to get the result: `[{"disk":{"name":"/dev/sdb"}}]`
[image]

How can I get the value in lookupvalue column if I want the output to look like this?
`[{"disk":"/dev/sdb","scope":"common"}]`

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

use in sql-server

```
SELECT disk,scope
FROM tblDataInfo
FOR JSON PATH;
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7903c24022ce43b21ff0d731d0dbaf7e)

in mysql

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('disk', disk, 'scope',scope)) 
from tblDataInfo
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Meysam Asadi, but I do not want the escape character backslash (\\) to be displayed. I want it to look like: [{"disk":"/dev/sdb","scope":"common"}]

Answer (score 0):

The escape characters are needed to properly deserialize the string.  To display the field values without escape characters deserialize the JSON.  Something like this

```
declare @json            nvarchar(max)=N'[{"disk":{"name":"\/dev\/sdb"}}]';

select json_value(disk, N'$.name') [name] 
from openjson(json_query(@json, N'$[0]'))
        with (disk        nvarchar(max) as json);
```

There are many different ways to open the JSON

```
select json_value(json_query(@json, N'$[0]'), N'$.disk.name') [name];
```

```
name
/dev/sdb
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server by default escapes `\` character. The only way to prevent this is to generate your object manually.

In this case, you will have to generate the whole object yourself

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
    '[{"disk":"',
    REPLACE(disk, '\', '\\'),
    '","scope":"',
    REPLACE(scope, '\', '\\'),
    '"}]')
FROM (VALUES
    ('/dev/sdb', 'common')
) AS t(disk, scope);
```

> `JSON_QUERY` is used in that question only to prevent escaping again in the outer `JSON PATH`